# How to upload file via ajax in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have used jQuery-File-Upload plugin ( https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload ) but it was not helpful.
this is my html:

```
<!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            <input type="hidden" class="hidden-token" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
        </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
    <div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

and my script:

```
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
        /*global window, $ */
        $(function () {
            'use strict';
            // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
            var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                            '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/',
                    uploadButton = $('<button/>')
                            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
                            .prop('disabled', true)
                            .text('Processing...')
                            .on('click', function () {
                                var $this = $(this),
                                        data = $this.data();
                                $this
                                        .off('click')
                                        .text('Abort')
                                        .on('click', function () {
                                            $this.remove();
                                            data.abort();
                                        });
                                data.submit().always(function () {
                                    $this.remove();
                                });
                            });
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                url: '/upload/artist/image',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                autoUpload: false,
                formData: {_token: $('.hidden-token').val()},
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
                // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
                // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
                // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
                disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                previewMaxWidth: 100,
                previewMaxHeight: 100,
                previewCrop: true,
                success: function(){
                  alert('ok');
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                },
            }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    var node = $('<p/>')
                            .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
                    if (!index) {
                        node
                                .append('<br>')
                                .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
                    }
                    node.appendTo(data.context);
                });
            }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
                var index = data.index,
                        file = data.files[index],
                        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
                if (file.preview) {
                    node
                            .prepend('<br>')
                            .prepend(file.preview);
                }
                if (file.error) {
                    node
                            .append('<br>')
                            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
                }
                if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
                    data.context.find('button')
                            .text('Upload')
                            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                        'width',
                        progress + '%'
                );
            }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
                    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
        });
    </script>
```

my routes.php :

```
Route::post('/upload/artist/image', function() {
    return view('upload.artist-image');
});
```

and finally in artist-image.php I use this simple code:

```
return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
```

But in my ajax does not have any response even in console and network (chrome inspect element) and always my upload return fail text in this plugin.

Comment: you should make some efforts to fix your problem, even after trying you cannot find anything then only you should ask questions along with your code so that people here can help you if there is somethign you are missing in your code.

Comment: Ok. sorry. I corrected it. @KhanShahrukh

Answer (score 5):

You cannot send files over (basic) AJAX (XMLHttpRequest).

You eighter need to use some "iframe" uploader, or XMLHttpRequest2.
I would go for XHR2.

```
/**
 * Read selected files locally (HTML5 File API)
 */
var filesToUpload = null;

function handleFileSelect(event)
{
    var files = event.target.files || event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    // Itterate thru files (here I user Underscore.js function to do so).
    // Simply user 'for loop'.
    _.each(files, function(file) {
        filesToUpload.push(file);
    });
}

/**
 * Form submit
 */
function handleFormSubmit(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = this,
        formData = new FormData(form);  // This will take all the data from current form and turn then into FormData

    // Prevent multiple submisions
    if ($(form).data('loading') === true) {
        return;
    }
    $(form).data('loading', true);

    // Add selected files to FormData which will be sent
    if (filesToUpload) {
        _.each(filesToUpload, function(file){
            formData.append('cover[]', file);
        });        
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'url/to/controller/action',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            // handle response
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            // Allow form to be submited again
            $(form).data('loading', false);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

/**
 * Register events
 */
$('#file-input').on('change', handleFileSelect);
$('form').on('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```